# How to move block to the left

Tags: right-to-left

I would like to move the block "Business Listings" to the left so that it is aligned with the left side of the page on the site: http://www.kids.yetzira.com/

Can someone please tell me how to do this.

I am trying to make the site rtl. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add `float:left` to the section-head div and `clear-both` to the article element below.